# How can I suppress the `Generating XXX` message for a cmake `add_custom_command`?

Tags: cmake

I'm working with CMake project that take a large set of input files and processes them to produce an even larger set of output files.  This is done with a single python script call.

In the CMake script, this is expressed as

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${OUTPUT_ARTIFACTS}
    COMMAND ...
    DEPENDS ${INPUT_ARTIFACTS}
)
```

It works fine on windows builds, but on Ubuntu, using makefile builds this fails because in the makefile, there's a "helpful" command in the style

```
@$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --blue --bold --progress-dir=/home/bdavis/git/hifi/build/CMakeFiles --progress-num=$(CMAKE_PROGRESS_1) "Generating [SUPER LONG LIST OF OUTPUT ARTIFACTS]"
```

On my test system this latter command is almost over 197 thousand characters, so when I run make it chokes with

```
/bin/sh: 1: eval: /usr/bin/cmake: Argument list too long
```

This is super frustrating since this isn't a critical part of the build, just status messaging, which is redundant in this case since the script producing the artifacts also emits output on a per-artifact basis.

Is there a mechanism to suppress the CMake `generating` message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `COMMENT` argument to `add_custom_command` (see [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html)). This doesn't completely suppress the message, but it will display your custom message instead of the automatically generated one:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${OUTPUT_ARTIFACTS}
    COMMAND ...
    DEPENDS ${INPUT_ARTIFACTS}
    COMMENT "Generating foo artifacts"
)
```